# Array multiple JSON Data output

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, curl

I'm relatively new and am currently learning php. I'm trying to work with JSON data right now. I'd like to echo all NODES, but I can't find a solution. Maybe somebody can help me.

**API:** https://flightplandatabase.com/dev/api#route

**API XML:** https://api.flightplandatabase.com/plan/62478

**What I want:** route.nodes[].ident <-- All nodes idents. Not only the first one

Currently I only get the first "NODE". Is it possible that I can get every NODE out at the same time without much effort?

```
    <?php

            $ch = curl_init();  

            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.flightplandatabase.com/plan/62478');
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

            $output = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch); 

            $finalarray = json_decode($output);

            $finalstring = json_encode($output);


    ?>
    <div>
        <p><?php echo $finalarray->route->nodes[0]->ident; ?></p>
    </div>
```

Hope you understand what I mean. :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: That api endpoint appears to be returning xml. I'm curious how `echo $finalarray->route->nodes[0]->ident;` returns anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you set it to print only this first `[0]`. 
Try use a for:

```
$nodes = $finalarray->route->nodes
for ($i=0; $i<count($nodes); $i++) {
 echo nodes[$i]->ident;
}
```

Plus, it is better to do:

```
json_decode($yourarray, true);
```

And

```
json_encode($yourarray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Works if: $nodes = $finalarray->route->nodes
for ($i=0; $i<count($nodes); $i++) {
 echo $finalarray->route->nodes[$i]->ident;
} - Thanks for helping. Does somebody know how I can seperate each node?